# CMake find_package(PythonInterp 3.7 REQUIRED) for Win32 platform

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I have some project which supposed to support `Win32` and `x64` platform.
Some code is generated by python script.
This script uses `python3` features.

In `CMakeLists.txt` I have something like this:

```
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
if (CMAKE_CL_64)
    set(MY_APP_PLATFORM "x64")
else()
    set(MY_APP_PLATFORM "Win32")
endif()

add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${MyApp_ROOT}/generator.py -p ${MY_APP_PLATFORM }
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PATH_GENERATED_SRC}
    COMMENT "Generating code..."
    VERBATIM
)
```

Quite simple.

Now when project for `x64` is used everything works like a charm, but when building for `Win32` (cmake have to generate separate project) `cmake` finds `python 2.7.2`.

Changing `CMakeLists.txt` this way:

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3.7 REQUIRED)
```

Leads to cmake failure.

Is there way to fix it, or do I have to correct pythons script to be `python2` compatible?

Or do I have to install `python3` for 32 and 64 bits to cover both platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CMake Module is `FindPython3.cmake` in your cmake distribution.

This should work:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter)

add_custom_command(TARGET MyApp
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE} ${MyApp_ROOT}/generator.py -p ${MY_APP_PLATFORM}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PATH_GENERATED_SRC}
    COMMENT "Generating code..."
    VERBATIM
)
```

It is available since cmake `3.12`.

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPython3.html)

Comment: It should be `COMPONENTS` - in CMake command options are **case-sensitive**.